# Extracting metadata from PNG image

Tags: java, image, imagemagick, png, metadata

I'm trying to extract metadata from a PNG image format. I'm using this library? http://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/

Even though it claims that PNG format is supported I get an error `File format is not supported` when I try it with a PNG image. From the source (in method `readMetadata` also it looks like that it doesn't support PNG format: http://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/source/browse/Source/com/drew/imaging/ImageMetadataReader.java?r=1aae00f3fe64388cd14401b2593b580677980884

I've also given this piece of code a try as well but it also doesn't extract the metadata on the PNG.

BTW, I'm adding metadata on PNG with imagemagick like this:

```
mogrify -comment "Test" Demo/myimage.png
```

Has anyone used this library for PNG format or are there other ways to extract metadata from PNG image?

Comment: Look at this page and the library there https://github.com/dragon66/icafe/wiki/More-cool-things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [PNGJ](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj) (I'm the developer)

See eg here an [example](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj/blob/master/src/test/java/ar/com/hjg/pngj/samples/SampleShowChunks.java) to dump all chunks. 
If you want to read a particular text chunk (recall that in PNG each textual metadata has a key and a value), you could write

```
 pngr.getMetadata().getTxtForKey("mykey")
```

A useful little Windows program to peek inside PNG chunk structure is [TweakPNG](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/)

Update: If you want to check all textual chunks (bear in mind that there are three types with some differences, but...)

```
PngReader pngr = FileHelper.createPngReader(new File(file));
pngr.readSkippingAllRows();
for (PngChunk c : pngr.getChunksList().getChunks()) {
      if (!ChunkHelper.isText(c))   continue;
      PngChunkTextVar ct = (PngChunkTextVar) c;
      String key = ct.getKey();
      String val = ct.getVal();
      // ... 
}
```

Bear also in mind that textual chunks with repeated keys are allowed.

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to go through all the key/value pairs? Rather than looking for a specific key with `pngr.getMetadata().getTxtForKey("mykey")` I want to go through all the key/value pairs in metadata for the image.

Comment: awesome! that works. thanks. Just for curiosity what are the three types?

Comment: @birdy: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.Anc-text  Basically: tEXt : Latin1 encoding for keys and values, zTXt: idem, but value is stored compressed, iTXt: UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Thanks. I was just going through the source of your project and had a question. wikipedia says the signature of png file starts with `137` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header However, in your source https://code.google.com/p/pngj/source/browse/pnjg/src/ar/com/hjg/pngj/PngHelperInternal.javahttps://code.google.com/p/pngj/source/browse/pnjg/src/ar/com/hjg/pngj/PngHelperInternal.java `PngHelperInternal` method `getPngIdSignature` it starts with `-119`. All others match except the first one. Why the difference?

Comment: Because in Java bytes are signed. At the bit level, they are the same number (137=256-119)