# Android exif data not able to get the data for key "Description"

Tags: android

Hi  I am trying to extract some custom data which store along with image metadata using the tag `Description`.

Using the the command line tool from linux `exiftool myImage.png`

I am getting the following data

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.10
File Name                       : myImage.png
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 1377 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2017:11:02 18:06:52+05:30
File Access Date/Time           : 2017:11:09 12:54:04+05:30
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2017:11:02 18:06:52+05:30
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : PNG
File Type Extension             : png
MIME Type                       : image/png
Image Width                     : 1000
Image Height                    : 1437
Bit Depth                       : 8
Color Type                      : RGB
Compression                     : Deflate/Inflate
Filter                          : Adaptive
Interlace                       : Noninterlaced
Pixels Per Unit X               : 3937
Pixels Per Unit Y               : 3937
Pixel Units                     : meters
Description                     : Hi....
Image Size                      : 1000x1437
Megapixels                      : 1.4
```

But when I am trying to get the data from android using [ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) for the key `Description` I am getting null value.

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);
String d = exif.getAttribute("Description");
```

Is there any problem with above code.

**Edit**

I can see the following data when I do debugging.

```
"exif"   (id=67)    
    mAttributes HashMap  (id=70)    
        [0] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=99)   
            key "WhiteBalance" (id=107) 
            value   "0" (id=108)    
        [1] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=100)  
            key "Flash" (id=112)    
            value   "0" (id=113)    
        [2] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=101)  
            key "LightSource" (id=114)  
            value   "0" (id=115)    
        [3] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=102)  
            key "Orientation" (id=116)  
            value   "0" (id=117)    
        [4] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=103)  
            key "ImageLength" (id=118)  
            value   "0" (id=119)    
        [5] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=104)  
            key "ImageWidth" (id=120)   
            value   "0" (id=86) 
    mFilename   "/storage/emulated/0/Download/doorKeyUser_3922.png" (id=76) 
    mHasThumbnail   false   
    mInputStream    null    
    shadow$_klass_  Class (android.media.ExifInterface) (id=68) 
    shadow$_monitor_    -2024965232 [0x874d7b90]
```

Comment: Can you get the exif time and so?

Comment: No using the code `String dt = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);` it's giving null.

Comment: Well then your post is not to the point. Can you extract any attribute then?

Comment: I wonder which 'path' you use. And how you obtained it.

Comment: Please give me a moment, I will post the details.

Comment: `(exiftool myImage.png` PNG files do not contain an exif header.

Comment: Thanks for the response,  is there any alternate solution I can use.

Comment: I consider this pretty bad formulated post as closed. Please post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct tag is `"ImageDescription"`

The corresponding constant [TAG_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#TAG_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION) was added in API 24, but you can use the version from [the support lib](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html)

Comment: I have tried that too, but still the return value id null, can I use png file, right now I am using it, and my target sdk version is 23

Comment: Of couse you can not use  a png file as such files do not contain an exif header. Only jpg files do.

Comment: I thought you could extract all tags except the description. As it appears that you have no tags at all, there is another problem

Comment: Thanks for the response, so is there any alternative I can use. I have to do it for png file.

Comment: @greenapps is right, the supported format are JPEG, DNG, CR2, NEF, NRW, ARW, RW2, ORF, PEF, SRW and RAF, so no PNG. It seems that PNG has its own metadata, including a description but I don't know of java library allowing to read them

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14526044/1283554) can be a starting point

Comment: Thanks, I will check it.